# Testing Route that relies on Middleware (Laravel / PhpUnit)

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I have an API that has a Middleware that checks the request and log the user by adding $user to the $request, so it is accessible on the Controller function when it reaches it.

API request -> Middleware -> Controller

How do I can run tests on the API endpoints without removing the Middleware? As it is important for the application flow currently. Or is coupling middleware with the controller a bad practice?

I thought about mocking the Middleware partially and replacing it on the Application instance, but didnt manage to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Middlewares are only removed if you use `WithoutMiddleware`. Remove this line from your test: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;`

Comment: @SystemGlitch I've removed it, but now it gives me an Unauthorized error (401). How do I replace part of the middleware (mock) so it validates my login? I'm using an third party JWT login system (auth0)

Comment: You need to log from the test itself using `$this->actingAs()` or `$this->be()` ([Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#session-and-authentication))

Comment: @SystemGlitch I'm not using sessions on the application (it's actually Lumen), so on the Middleware I am binding the JWT user to $request->user. Thanks for your replies!